# Flutter - Problema al generar código injectable_generator

Tags: flutter, build

Tengo error al generar código, estoy implementando GetIt y hasta ahora no lo he logrado por este mensaje de error:

[SEVERE] injectable_generator:injectable_config_builder on lib/injection.dart (cached):

Stack Overflow

en Pubspec.yaml

```
#dependency injection
  injectable: ^2.1.2
  get_it: ^7.2.0

dev_dependencies:
  flutter_test:
    sdk: flutter

flutter_lints: ^2.0.0
  build_runner:
  injectable_generator:
```

Mi código del injection.dart

```
import 'package:get_it/get_it.dart';
import 'package:injectable/injectable.dart';

final getIt = GetIt.instance;

@InjectableInit()
void configureDependencies() => $initGetIt(getIt);
```

El comando que uso para generar código:

```
flutter pub run build_runner build --delete-conflicting-outputs
```

El mensaje de error:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]